# Select word in dB that is part of a given word

Tags: sql

I've created a  database that contains a bunch of words such as `itch`, `mitch`, `hell`. Is there any query I can make so that if given a variable, for example `Mitchell`, it will return me the words it can find inside of it that also exist in the dB such as `itch`, `mitch`, `hell`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you are after with [locate()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_locate)

In MySQL the following would work

```
SELECT 
    id,
    word, 
    LOCATE(word, LOWER('Mitchell')) 
FROM 
    words
WHERE  LOCATE(word, LOWER('Mitchell')) > 0
```

You can play with it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2fdd22b/2/0